# Help using delta-epsilon Theory

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

The question is show $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^{3}+1}$$ is continuous at $x=2$.

I've got it to $$\frac{|x-2||-x^{2}-2x-4|}{|9(x^{3}+1)|}$$

But from here i don't understand how i pick my values for $\delta$ and how to use this value to come up with the final answer.

I believe $|x-2|=\delta<1$ so $x\in(1,3)$ Does this mean $$0 < \delta < min{[3,\frac{18 \epsilon}{5}]}$$ or not because i am not sure at all.

Any help would be appreciated many thanks

Comment: @mvw looks good to me.  You are on the right track. restrict delta.  Then you find a the minimal value that $\frac{|x^2+2x+4|}{9|x^3+1|}$ could be. Then $\delta < \epsilon/k \implies |f(x) - L|<\epsilon$

Comment: @DougM so do i restrict delta by having x=1 or 3, sub these values in to $\frac{|-x^{2}-2x-4|}{9|x^{3}+1|}$< \epsilon this gives either $\frac{5}{18}$ and $\frac{1}{252}$. so the smaller would be $252 \epsilon$? this is the part I'm confused about? So id have $0 < \delta < min[1, 252\epsilon]$

Comment: sorry maximal a value that that fraction can be (7/18)... and $\delta < min (1,\epsilon \frac{18}{7})$

Comment: @DougM okay see how you get $\frac{18}{7}$ but why do you take the positive values in the top line why have you got $x^{2}+2x+4$ and when i used long division using $x-2$ i got $-x^{2}-2x-4$? i don't understand why you take the positive equation?

Comment: It is an absolute value.  They are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Suppose that we first of all specify that $\delta\lt 1$. Then $1\lt x\lt 3$, and therefore $|-x^2-2x-4|\lt 19$ and $9|x^3+1|\gt 9$.